# Mixed up browser sessions

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, session-cookies

We have 2 asp.net MVC applications installed on the same backend-server, using the same port. Opening both applications in the same browser causes their sessions to interfere.

I'm wondering how this could be avoided without touching to the server-infrastructure ? 
I was thinking about clearing all sessions at startup of both applications but I'm not sure how to do this or whether this would be a good idea ?

Answer (score 0):

If the sites are on the same subdomain/domain then they'll share cookies by default. This is because cookies are domain-bound. There's no way around *that*, but you can customize the cookie name each application uses, so even though they'll both receive the same cookies, they'll only mess with the one that belongs to them. For sessions, this can be achieved by adding the `cookieName` attribute to your `<sessionState>` element in the site's Web.config:

```
<sessionState ... cookieName="Website1_SessionId" />
```

You'll need to similarly customize the auth cookie name, if you're handling authentication on both sites as well.